# Amazon S3 does not return a response or throw error when running on EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk

I am attempting to connect to an S3 bucket using the access key and secret key credentials.
This works correctly on my local machine. However, when I try to run it on an EC2 instance the execution seems to stop at the line `result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(request);`. There are no exceptions. There is simply no response. I would really appreciate any help.

**Java code**

```
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey)))
        .withRegion(region).build();

    ListObjectsV2Result result = null;
    List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = null;
    String continuationToken = null;

    System.out.println("Starting loop to request information");

    int count = 1;
    do {
         ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request();
         request.setBucketName(bucket);
         request.setContinuationToken(continuationToken);

         System.out.println("Placing request information #" + count);
         result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(request);
         System.out.println("Got response for request #" + count++);

         continuationToken = result.getNextContinuationToken();
         objects = result.getObjectSummaries();

         for (S3ObjectSummary os : objects) {
             System.out.println(os.getKey());
         }
    } while (continuationToken != null);
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.466</version>
    </dependency>
```

**S3 Bucket policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1563965234895",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1563965231235",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/xyz_dev",
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx-yyy-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx-yyy-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: make sure instance has internet access, and that your creds are configured the same

Comment: If execution stops, it sounds like an exception that was caught and ignored.

Comment: Why not just attach an IAM role to the EC2 instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html and allow that role in the bucket policy?

Comment: @AndrewA. I haven't tried that specifically but I did try to assign the EC2 IAM role to the Bucket policy. Let me try again.

Comment: Are you running in a private subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your responses. I had multiple issues with the code (it was not an issue with the Amazon S3)

1. It was the infamous error `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_REGION` but only occurring on EC2. It was not caught in the try-catch block surrounding the code but was in the HTTP response.
2. My project is on Spring Boot it had incorrectly imported different versions of aws-sdk modules
3. I had another POM entry `hadoop-aws` that had its own version of aws-sdk

Fix:

1. Added individual aws-sdk module entries instead of the full aws-java-sdk
       
       
           com.amazonaws
           aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp

   ```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Added exclusions to hadoop-aws

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.1</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
               <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that your project is a Spring BOOT project.

We are working on a document that will show you how to write a Spring BOOT application that invokes AWS Services (in the document, DynamoDB is used as an example) and deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

When you do so, there are a few things you need to do to make a Spring BOOT app work, such as:

1. Set the port that Spring Boot listens on by adding a new environment variable named **SERVER_PORT**, with the value 5000.
2. Add a new variable named **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** and specify your access
   key value.
3. Add a new variable named **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY** and specify your secret key value.

To create an AWS Service client, use a **EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider** - like this to use the environment variables.

```
Region region = Region.US_EAST_1; DynamoDbClient ddb =

 DynamoDbClient.builder()
             .region(region)
             .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
             .build();
```

When the document is done, I will post it here.

Hope this helps...